# IBM Worklight - Which features a Native app cannot use?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have a pure native application and wanted to integrate with the worklight (using the Worklight Native SDK).

Which of the below features the native application can not use?

1. Unified SMS/Push Notifications
2. Remote Disable
3. Remote Notify
4. Adapters
5. Authentication framework
6. Direct Update
7. JSON Store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Native application that uses the Worklight SDK does not support:

1. Direct Update

   This feature is meant for updating web resources; this feature is currently supported only in Hybrid apps.
2. JSONStore

   This feature is currently supported up to Worklight 6.1.0.x only in Hybrid apps (for the Android and iOS envrionments)

Comment: Thanks Idan, what about the other features i have mentioned here

Comment: I mentioned in my answer only those that are not supported. This means the remaining are supported.